# AC to DC rectifier, smoking

Tags: power-supply, rectifier

I have built a LM317 power supply, which is working nicely through a DC wall wart and wanted to hook up to an AC transformer so it can run off mains and free up my wall wart, so I made up the below circuit

[image: AC to DC]

And hooked it up to my 240V to 18V transformer on bread board, and had smoke coming out of it. Note only the 18V side was connected up to my bread board not the 240V part!

Is that correct that diagram. I just want to be able to have AC mains (240V Australia) through a 500mA-1A fuse into the transformer then rectified off to my power supply.

Am I missing something?

NOTE: In the diagram AC+ is 18V tap out of the tra

Comment: Sorry about the delay steeped out for a while, the smoke was out of the diodes I believe. I saw smoke and disconnected the circuit. The DC+ and DC- will be connecting to the input of my power supply circuit. The AC- point isn't connected to ground that is my mistake it is connected to the 0V mark on my transformer.

Comment: Polarity of DC may have been reversed - highly likely.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with the circuit as it's currently drawn.  There's a problem off-diagram somewhere, or in the translation.  Perhaps one or more of the diodes is reversed?  The DC outputs have low impedance?  Your transformer is putting out much more than 18V?  It's hard to say, we *still* need more information. (Note: Cleared obsolete comments).

Comment: I assume you have large capacitors after the rectification stage?

Comment: any chance what you thought were 1N4004s were not in fact 1N4004s?

Comment: I have purchased some new 1N4004s gonna give it another go, and no cap after my power supply circuit has a 2200uF cap on it plus 2 smaller caps

Comment: Ok I have it working may of have connected it up wrong or used the wrong diode's maybe. What size cap should I use for smoothing. Based on 18v out of transformer, 0.5A max current, 50Hz will a 2200uF @ 25v work?

Comment: @AshleyHughes, how much will you allow the voltage output to fluctuate?

Comment: It is working ok with the 2200uF no seeing any problems other than a heating one it gets very hot at the moment on the heat sink I am going to lower the input at the AC end to reduce the over all dissipation that the regulator has to do which in turn should reduce the heat

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What little you show of your schematic is correct.  That leaves a list of things you could have gotten wrong or are wrong of the schematic you showed.

Check that the diodes are really all oriented as you show.  The cathode will have a silvery band painted around the diode body near its end.

Check the open circuit voltage coming out of the full wave bridge.  With no load and with even a little bit of capacitance there, in theory you should get 18V * sqrt(2) - 1.4V = 24V.  However, the transformer is likely putting out more than 18V under no load.

Are you sure whatever is connected to the DC output can handle up to 30V without damage or excessive current?

Are you sure the transformer is intended for 240V input, not 110V?

Are you really sure neither side of the transformer secondary is connected to your ground?  That would short two of the diodes.  The transformer secondary should *only* be connected to the diodes.

Comment: I do believe I connected it wrong the 1st time as this time it has worked well for me, I have a 10uF cap across the output, then it goes off into my LM317 based power supply, which has a 2200uF across its input.